# How can I keep my paint brushes long lasting?

Tags: paint-brushes

I am not a trained artist.My paint brushes are getting damage easily after finishing one or two creations.Below I have added the images of the brush that I am using now.I do not know what are best types of paint brushes that I can use corresponding to acrylic color that I am using or the colors that are suitable to the paint brush that I am using.

[image]

Currently I am using these brushes.Also I am mainly using Camel Fabric acrylic colors.This one.

[image]

Comment: What types of brushes are you using? What types of paints? How are you treating them when using them? When cleaning them? When storing them? Please add this information, as currently this is very vague.

Comment: Welcome! Please do add more details about the sort of art you are working on and materials you are working with, because there are a lot of possible solutions to your problem :)

Comment: I'm closing as too broad for right now because "best types" is a huge scope, and "keep long lasting" does depend on factors like Allison pointed out. For example, we already have questions on [oil paint brushes](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2142/how-do-i-maintain-my-oil-paint-brushes). When you get a chance, go ahead and [edit] your question with a few more details so the community can provide specific, helpful answers!

Comment: vote to reopen. The materials used do not really matter because the universal answer, as Joachim has provided, is keep your brushes clean when not using them (and wet when you are.)

Comment: @AllisonC I have added more information regarding my query.

Comment: @Joachim Thanking for the kind reply.I have modified my question.Have a look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I keep my paint brushes long lasting?

Awaiting more specific information, I can already tell it's best to **rinse your brushes directly after every use**. Whether it's oil or acrylic you're working with, the brushes can easily be cleaned with a little soap and water. I use general hand soap bars for this - nothing fancy: don't be persuaded by the overpriced "artist soap" (but more on that later on).

I leave my brushes in a jar with soapy water at all times. I fixed a spring on top of the jar to hold the brushes, so that the bristles don't get squished as they dry, preventing deformation.

You can adapt the spring from a spring holder like the one here:

[image: Spring paint brush hanger]

Using a jar instead of a tin allows for more soapwater, slower evaporation, and fewer refills.

**When the paint has dried** up already, I usually either **soften it up again** in that same jar - but you have to wait for days if not weeks (depending on the size of your brush) - or use a small hammer to **hammer the paint out** (this I only really do with acrylic paint). This is bad practice for high-quality brushes, but with those you wouldn't let it come this far in the first place :) And, nevertheless, a usable bad-quality brush is still better than an unusable high-quality one.

> What are best types of paint brushes?

That is a different question altogether, but, in the light of your main question, the **brushes with the greatest longevity are usually those with plastic (nylon, polyester) bristles**, as they are less easily damaged.

Natural hairs usually paint better (depending on the paint you work with, your style, the size, etc., and high-quality acrylic bristles are improving), but they are more susceptible to degradation, as organic fibers tend to be, so you have to make sure you take good care of them.

If you're starting out with painting, I'd suggest using hog hair bristles for oils and synthetic brushes for acrylic paint. They are both cheap and relatively resilient, and abusing or losing them while getting used to the painting process won't be the proverbial end of the world.

Comment: +1 - its pretty simple, clean your brushes and they will last longer. Just want to mention that acrylics and other fast drying paints will dry on the brush if you don't keep them wet. If its oil based paints you are using, you can wash with soap and water (I use dish soap or green soap bar) but be sure to rinse out the oils very well with turps or mineral spirits first.

Comment: I do recommend that artist soap btw (the green bar) as it does a nice job of cleaning and conditioning the brushes. I have had many of my brushes for 30+ years and they are still going strong... the same brushes, when I forget to do a good wash, can go bad after one use.

Answer (score 1):

Keep them moist, clean them. If wooden be careful of leaving submerged as the coating will peel or warp them. Personally I keep hold of my dilapidated brushes too as a distressed brush can give some interesting effects when combined with different media....

Answer (score 1):

If you clean them before the paint or substance (varnish, oil paint, etc.) dries on the bristles, they will last a really long time.  I've kept both cheap and expensive brushes for over 30 years or more.

[I use this kind of brush soap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0027AEANE).  If I've used an oil-based substance, I'll clean it first with mineral spirits, then use the soap.  The soap will condition the bristles and clean the particles out from between the hairs.

Also, don't use laquer thinner to clean your brushes!  That stuff will eat the finish off the handles and damage the brush hairs themselves.  That being said, I've done this before and still kept the brushes (with missing finishes) for use anyway.

Old brushes that have distorted brush ends can be used for effects and for other projects where you don't need to do fine work.  I use my old, not-so-nice brushes for applying glue and varnish.  And I clean them anyway, just like I would my good brushes.  This policy keeps my good brushes good because I don't have to use them for not-so-fine applications.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from cleaning them in a timely fashion. You might be using them the wrong way. If your "pushing" your brush, its going to wear out very fast. You want to drag your brush. Sometimes you may want to push, for the effect, but when you do, it has a negative effect on the brushes longevity. Also, after you clean your brush and you've gotten all of the paint out, drag it across a bar of soap, then reshape it, and let it dry that way. Brushes that hold their shape longer, also last longer.